# Calling a jquery function in telerik radgrid image button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radgridview

I have one problem with RadGrid and Jquery.

I have a Telerik RadGrid which contains 2 imagebuttons. When I click on imagebuttons, these buttons should call the jquery functions. I'm not getting how to implement this.

This is my jQuery function:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Link1").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#panelText').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: without your js/jquery code, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: you should post final Mark-up to see is your scrips is correct

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like

```
$(function () {
    $("#" + <%= Link1.ClientID %>).click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#' + <%= panelText.ClientID %>).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Once the controls are rendered on the page, they get assigned unique ClientID's which you don't have direct access to in your JS -- but you can use this method to inject the correct ClientID by grabbing it from the server.